Who is on board the Cameo?
In the 1976 Columbo episode Last Salute to the Commodore, there is a scene where Columbo pulls his signature move of making the murderer uncomfortable, this time by sharing a couch with them:

This scene takes place on a boat docked in the harbor, and through the window behind them, we can see the neighboring boat. Its nameplate tellingly reads Cameo and throughout the scene, we can see three people on the bridge of that ship, looking directly into the camera. It seems to be a man, a woman and a child (though I could be wrong about that part).
Who is giving the cameo appearance here?

Could you provide a link to that scene?

I suspect the name of the boat has nothing to do with a cameo appearance. What leads you to think it is special?

@Paulie_D The way that the actors behave indicates that they are not ordinary extras. Usually you want extras to blend in with the background, but these guys behave as if they were aware of the camera. I will try to get a video of the scene, maybe that will make it clear.

Perhaps they weren't extras...perhaps they were real people?

@Paulie_D If you had a source for that, you would have an answer. Until then, your guess is as good as mine.
